# "Directory not found" error with Docker-Compose up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm on WIndows 10 Home Edition (running VirtualBox which is probably my issue. I have a shared folder in VirtualBox set up to c:/Courses/Containerization/frontend that will allow this folder to be used. When I use the related dependencies using the "docker" PATH, everything wires up fine, but I can't seem to avoid an error when I use docker-compose. Any ideas as to why?

Folder structure:

```
$ ls
build/  docker-compose.yaml  Dockerfile.dev  package.json  public/  README.md  src/
```

Dockerfile.dev file:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN ls -al
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: ['npm', 'run', 'test']
```

Error:

```
tests_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
tests_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
tests_1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
tests_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
tests_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
tests_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
tests_1  | npm ERR! enoent
tests_1  |
tests_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
web_1    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1    | npm ERR! syscall open
web_1    | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
web_1    | npm ERR! errno -2
web_1    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
web_1    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1    | npm ERR! enoent
web_1    |
web_1    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
tests_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-22T07_34_11_270Z-debug.log
frontend_tests_1 exited with code 254
web_1    | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-22T07_34_11_338Z-debug.log
frontend_web_1 exited with code 254
```

Comment: Can you share the output of this command in your Dockerfile - RUN ls -al ?

Comment: Your `volumes:` are overwriting the code in the image, and telling Docker to ignore any updates to the `package.json` file.  Does deleting those blocks help?  You can still use a normal host Node environment for day-to-day development and Docker for deployment.